# Get date of every second Tuesday of a month

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a way to find out the date of every second Tuesday of a month using T-SQL syntax?

E.g. in March it is the 12th, in April it's the 9th.

Comment: What do you have as input, or what is your desired output? Are you giving us a single `datetime` value and we have to find the relevant day from that same month? Or do you want a table of all of these dates?

Comment: Output should be **2013-03-12**, I I want to loop for any month of a year - it's dynamic for a report.

Comment: I've updated my answer to find the second tuesday of the current month. But note that, we don't generally try to write *loops* in SQL - we try to find a *set-based* approach - telling SQL Server the shape of the final result set and letting *it* work out how to compute it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can find all 'second tuesdays' in 2013.

```
select 
dateadd(day, 8, datediff(day, 1, dateadd(month, n, '2013-01-07')) / 7 * 7) date
from 
(values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) t(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what the actual required inputs and outputs are, all I can give you at the moment is a predicate for identifying a date as the second tuesday of its month:

```
DATEPART(day,@Date) between 8 and 14 and --Find the second one in the month
DATEPART(weekday,@Date) = DATEPART(weekday,'20130319') --Make sure its a Tuesday
```

(I use a fixed, known Tuesday, so as to avoid having to know what [`DATEFIRST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181598.aspx) settings are in effect when the query is run)

---

This finds the appropriate Tuesday for the current month, but obviously `@Date` could be set to any date of interest:

```
declare @Date datetime
set @Date =  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

;with Numbers as (select n from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) t(n)),
PotentialDates as (select DATEADD(day,n,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',@Date),'20010108')) as Date
from Numbers
)
select * from PotentialDates where DATEPART(weekday,Date) = DATEPART(weekday,'20130319')
```

(And, hopefully also obviously, the query could be part of a larger query, where `@Date` was instead a column value, and so this can form part of a set-based approach to the entire piece of work)

Answer (score 2):

This code will give you every 1st and 3rd Sunday of the month.

```
declare @dt datetime
select @dt = '12/01/2014'

select dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,'',@dt),'') - datepart(dw,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,'',@dt),'')+0)+ 8
select dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,'',@dt),'') - datepart(dw,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,'',@dt),'')+0)+ 22
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer does not work for months starting on Sunday ( it points to the second Sunday instead).

```sql
SELECT @dt AS input_date,

    DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @dt), 0) --truncate date to month start

    -- DATEPART(@month_start) returns month start's weekday, with Sunday starting 1;
    -- Since Sunday starts at 1, we need to perform proper adjustment - move date 6 days forward (7 week days - 1 for sunday) forward and find its datepart, which will be 7
    -- Result: month starting sunday, datepart returns 7; month starting Mon we return 1 (datepart of Mon + 6 days = Sunday, which is 1), month starting tue, we return 2
    -- Effectivelly, datepart offset will always point last Sunday of previous month
    - DATEPART(dw, 
            6
            + DATEADD(mm,datediff(mm,0,@dt),0) --truncate date to month start
        ) 
        
    -- Since we found last Sunday of previous month, we need to add 7
    + 7 AS CORRECT,

    dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,'',@dt),'') - datepart(dw,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,'',@dt),'')+0)+ 8 AS sometimes_correct
```

Image that shows shows correct answer relative to the answer by Pravin Pandit:

[image: 1]

We can extend this rationale for finding first Tue of the month and create a function that does that, so for any input date, it will find 1st Tue of the month in question:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.f_time_floor_1st_tue(@date DATETIME2(3))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    
            DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @date), 0) --truncate date to month start

        -- DATEPART(@month_start) returns month start's weekday, with Sunday starting 1;
        -- Since Sunday starts at 1, we need to perform proper adjustment - move date 6 days forward (7 week days - 1 for sunday) forward and find its datepart, which will be 7
        -- Result: month starting sunday, datepart returns 7; month starting Mon we return 1 (datepart of Mon + 6 days = Sunday, which is 1), month starting tue, we return 2
        -- Effectivelly, datepart offset will always point last Sunday of previous month
        -- Extending this logic for finding first Tuesday, Tuesday should always return 7 we need to move Tue datepart (3) by 4  ( which is 7 days in the week minus 3 
        - DATEPART(dw, 
                4 -- 4 is adjustment so that DATEPART returns 7 for all months starting Tue
                + DATEADD(mm,datediff(mm,0,@date),0) --truncate date to month start
            ) 
        
        -- Since we found last weekday of previous month, we need to add 7
        + 7
    
    ;
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you current month's  Patch Tuesday

```
Declare @Date DATETIME = Getdate()

--Set  @Date = DAtefromParts(2022,01,01) -- for testing

Declare @PT DATETIME
Declare @WeekDay DATETIME
Declare @CM varchar(30)

Declare @FD DATETIME = DAtefromParts(DATEPART(yyyy,@date), DATEPART(mm,@date),01) --FirstDayof the month
print @FD

SET @WeekDay = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@FD) --No of WeekDay

if  @WeekDay =1
   Begin 
   
   Set @PT = DateAdd(D,9,@FD)
   end 

else if @WeekDay =2
   Begin 
 
   Set @PT = DateAdd(D,8,@FD)
   end 
else if @WeekDay =3
   Begin 
     Set @PT = DateAdd(D,7,@FD)
   end
else if @WeekDay =4
   Begin 
 
   Set @PT = DateAdd(D,13,@FD)
   end 
else if @WeekDay =5
   Begin 

   Set @PT =  DateAdd(D,12,@FD)
   end 
else if  @WeekDay =6
   Begin 

   Set @PT =  DateAdd(D,11,@FD)
   end 
else if @WeekDay =7
   Begin 
    Set @PT =  DateAdd(D,10,@FD)
   End 


Print @PT
```