# How to calculate previous year same day of week from month suppose first Monday of month would be last year first Monday of that month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to calculate same day of week from last year like first Monday of May this year would be last year first Monday of May and so on for all days.

```
SELECT 
    ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12) + 
        ((SELECT day_of_week 
          FROM sys_calendar.calendar 
          WHERE calendar_date = CURRENT_DATE) -
          (SELECT day_of_week 
           FROM sys_calendar.calendar 
           WHERE calendar_date = ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12)))
```

I did the above thing but for the dates like 7th April 2021 is 1st Wednesday from month is taking 8th April 2020 which is 2nd Wednesday from month but I want 1st April 2020 to be calculated.

Sample is

```
2021/4/7 to 2020/4/1
2021/4/14 to 2020/4/8
```

This kind of calculations I want

Comment: 25/May/2021 is Tuesday, You want to know what day is for 25/May/2020 (Monday) ?

Comment: No I want to calculate 25/may/2021 is 4th Tuesday so what will be 4th Tuesday from May 2020

Comment: The editor has a code formatting option.

Comment: We still need sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? Its a rather odd requirement.

Comment: As a starting point I would recommend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565151/get-date-of-every-second-tuesday-of-a-month

Comment: `FROM sys_calendar.calendar` I see that you have `calendar` table. Do you have a column that indicate the day of the week ? If you don't, add it in and use it in your query

Comment: The `add_months()` is an Oracle syntax, there is no such built-in function in MS SQL Server. Please make sure you use relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a suggestion which may be usable for you, despite of all correct comments and queries above.
If what you said is a **common** query in your system and it is not what you want to query JUST FOR NOW, I  suggest you to create a `Dim_Date` in your database and use it to find information about your date without using complicated slow queries.
This is what comes from my exprience I hope it helps.

---

I also searched and found a good table for you in the link below. It is a xlsx file which is attached at the end of the article. Download and import to your database then use it with code below.
[Date Dimension File](https://support.sisense.com/kb/en/article/date-dimension-file)

---

The Code I used was this:

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT
--- The Number You Want ----
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YearMonthNum,DayName ORDER BY DateNum) AS DayWeekNumber 
    ,YearMonthNum
    ,DayName
    ,Date
    ,DateNum
    ,MonthNum
    ,DayNumOfWeek
    ,Year
FROM dbo.dimDate Dim --- The Excel I imported
) 
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM X X1
JOIN dbo.MyTable T1 -- My Table And my Date Column
    ON T1.myDate = X1.Date
JOIN X X2 ON X2.Year = X1.Year-1   -- I wanted last year match so (-1). use (-n) for n years ago  
            AND X2.MonthNum = X1.MonthNum
            AND X2.DayNumOfWeek = X1.DayNumOfWeek
            AND X2.DayWeekNumber = X1.DayWeekNumber
```

---

[image: Here Is Result Image]

Comment: How will you use dimdate for that can you please  give me any idea I am new to this.

Comment: I see you have suggested a tag edit on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67681644/auto-increment-alphabet-in-sql-stored-procedure) question - but how do you know which RDBMS tag is the one intended by the OP?

Comment: "Indexing and Partitioning" doesn't seem especially relevant to the question.

Comment: @DaleK yes I just think of he decides to use a Dim so he will need good indexes for a better performance so i said it.

Comment: @Ajs Go the link and download the excel file from the end of the article. then import it in your database. there is a column in excel name is <Date>. you can join it with you date column in you own table. I am adding the code to answer

Comment: @El.Hum how does having a date table allow the OP to get the same day of the month last year, i.e. from the 2nd Tuesday of May 2021, OP wants to arrive at the 2nd Tuesday of May 2020? Your answer doesn't address that as far as I can see.

Comment: @DaleK I added an image. the query is a bit customized due to my database and tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232888/discussion-between-el-hum-and-dale-k).

Comment: El.Hum thanks for your solution It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is not going to be an easy one. It will most likely require a lookup table providing the weekday of each first day of the month for some years. From there the remaining calculations can be developed.

In that sense, **this post is not** going to be **an "answer"** but rather a longer *comment* which needs some formatting and a snippet for illustration.

When playing around in JavaScript I found a fairly direct way of doing this kind of *n-th weekday calculation for a given year and month* (this could be used to calculate a suitable lookup-table for your database):

```js
function createDate2(a){ // [2020,3,1,3] = [year,month,weekday, n-th occurence of weekday in month]
   const d=new Date(a[0],a[1],1); // create first day of the month
   d.setDate((a[2]-d.getDay()-6)%7 + a[3]*7);  // adjust to a[3]-th occurrence of the given weekday a[2]
   return d
 }
// weekday numbering: 0-Sunday, 1-Monday, 2-Tuesday ... 6-Saturday
// extend the Date prototype:
Date.prototype.getDate2=function(){ return [this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),this.getDay(),-~(this.getDate()/7)]; } // returns an array: [year,month,weekday, n-th occurence of weekday in month]

// calculate the third Thursday in each month for 2023:
for (let d,m=0;m<12;m++) 
  console.log(createDate2([2023,m,4,3])
              .toLocaleDateString("en-US",{weekday:'long',year:'numeric',month:'long',day:'numeric'})
             );
```

Maybe it is still useful for someone? ... For example, in extracting some parts of it for an SQL-based answer?

Comment: El.Hum Thank you for helping me for this. It is giving result as I expected.